# get div from HTML with Python

Tags: python, html, regex

I want to get a value inside certain div from a HTML page

```
    <div class="well credit">

      <div class="span2">
          <h3><span>
              $ 5.402 
          </span></h3>
      </div>

    </div>
```

I've done it with regular expressions ( re.seach() ) but it take too long to find the div since it's a huge html.

Is there a way to do this faster but with no external libraries?

Thanks

Comment: Well. consider using `lxml`. It is a built-in

Comment: Sorry if this is a facile suggestion, but if you know exactly how the `div` is going to be encoded, why not just use `find`, possibly recursively?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)!

to get everything with `<div>` tag just do:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)#make soup that is parse-able by bs
soup.findAll('div')
```

to get the value inside of span you could do:

```
soup.find('span').get_text()
```

there are tons of differnt methods of getting the informaton you need

Good Luck hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly :). I used 
    credits = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : " well credit"})
to be a little more specific, and there was more divs with credit on the html

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy might also be a solution for this. Please read http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

```
x = sel.xpath('//div[@class="span2"]')
for i in x:
    print i.extract()
```

Output:

```
<div class="span2">
    <h3><span>
        $ 5.402 
    </span></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has only one HTML parser in the standard library and it's pretty low-level, so you'll have to install *some* sort of HTML parsing library if you want to work with HTML.

[lxml](http://lxml.de/) is by far the fastest:

```
import lxml.html

root = lxml.html.parse(handle)
price = root.xpath('//div[@class="well credit"]//span/@text')[0]
```

If you want it to be even faster, use `root.iter` and stop parsing the HTML once you hit the right element.