# I want to extract the html from a particular div class named "se_component_wrap sect_dsc __se_component_area"

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

I have already got a working python script, but i want to automate the url fetching from a page..I just need all the html code inside the div class se_component_wrap sect_dsc __se_component_area but currently i'm getting the html of the whole page

```py
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from fetch import *

my_url=('https://m.post.naver.com/viewer/postView.nhn?volumeNo=20163796&memberNo=29747755')
#Opening Client
uClient = uReq(my_url)
#Opening the client
page_html = uClient.read()
#Closing connection
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
clear_file=page_soup.prettify()
with open("test.txt","w", encoding="utf-8") as outp:
    outp.write(clear_file)
print (page_soup)

fetcher()
```

I expect the output to be the html code that's contained in that division instead of the complete page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get div from HTML with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975400/get-div-from-html-with-python)

Comment: That outputs the text in the page.. I want the html code of the division..

Comment: Your cord is currently designed to scrape the entire page.  What division tag are you wanting?  There are 100s of division tags on the target page.

Comment: se_component_wrap sect_dsc __se_component_area

Comment: althought i want all the code inside that division tag..

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward way would be:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")    
for div in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'se_component_wrap sect_dsc __se_component_area'}):
        print div
```

Comment: what's ediv ? is it a function of soup

Comment: I am sorry, it was a typo. I have edited my answer.

Comment: It doesn't print anything.. i used it with other class name.. and it only printed the line

Comment: Make sure you define your soup variable with the content of the page. I have edited the code once more. Use it appropriately in your existing code. It should work

Comment: ```python from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from fetch import *

my_url=('https://m.post.naver.com/viewer/postView.nhn?volumeNo=20163796&memberNo=29747755')
#Opening Client
uClient = uReq(my_url)
#Opening the client
page_html = uClient.read()
#Closing connection
uClient.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
for div in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'se_component_wrap sect_dsc __se_component_area'}):
        print (div)
``` Still doesn't work